# Run Selenium tests in new window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to record a test using Selenium GUI (in Firefox). The application uses an image as hyperlink as shown below:

`<a class="mainheading" align="center" target="_blank" href="https://myapps.web.com/prepaid/customer/index.jsp">
<img width="256" height="57" border="0" alt="customer" src="images/customer.jpg"/>
</a>`

Now, when we click on above image, the `a href` tag opens another window. Once the new window is open, I need to perform rest of the tests in that window. The problem is when I record the test, the Selenium GUI has no way to understand that whatever actions I am performing is in the new window. Therefore, even though it records the actions appropriately, when I run a pre-recorded test, I get an error saying that the element not found. I figured that this happens because Selenium tries to find the element in the original window only (and not in the new window that got opened due to above `a href`).

I tried to Google, but the solutions I got were not matching to my situation above (i.e. `a href` opens new window as opposed to `window.open`). Can someone please advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the driver window handles like so:

```
// Get a list of window identities
List<string> windowIdentities = driver.WindowHandles.ToList();

// Switch control over to the other window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowIdentities[1]);
```

This is written in C#, but it shouldn't be too different if you're writing it in a different language.  Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to move to the new window before you perform actions to it.  For that, you can use switchTo.window if you are using webdriver, else in ide, there should be selectwindow to move to the appropriate window and then continue your actions there.